# When multiple transactions insert the same value at the same time, why except one get a duplicate exception?

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

I don't understand `INSERT sets an exclusive lock on the inserted row.` part of this document.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

In below part,

```sql
Session 1:
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);

Session 2:
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);

Session 3:
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

I thought they would go in the order below

1. First transaction got exclusive lock for number 1 row.(didn't committed yet)
2. Second transaction also try to get exclusive lock.
3. Second transaction is going to wait, because First transaction already has exclusive lock.

But they didn't like above, the document said

> The operations by sessions 2 and 3 both result in a duplicate-key error and they both request a shared lock for the row.

I don't understand why they got duplicate exception.
For a duplicate error to occur, the row must already be committed.
But they didn't. First transaction didn't commit yet.

Comment: Are you sure autocommit is not on? see
```select @@autocommit```

Comment: You have to look at mysql's internals to get a full understanding. My guess is that mysql indicates in the index records that value 1 is being inserted, hence the duplicate key error. The behaviour is consistent with the documentation.

Comment: I have tested again just now. Autocommit is not on. When I execute insert operation in session 2, session 2 was waiting continuously.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because before inserting an unique value (unique index), InnoDB has to do a search (secondary index scan), this will create next-key locks (next-key locks = record locks + gap locks).

Because there is a gap lock, doing insertion will require transaction to accquire the Insert Intention Locks first. The purpose of this lock is only to allow different transactions to insert rows into a gap at the same time if the rows are not duplicate. If the rows are duplicate then duplicate-key error will be raised.

In this example, transaction 1 accquired next-key locks from the minimum value to 1, then exclusive lock on 1 and inserted the row before committing. Transaction 2 and 3 accquired Insert Intention Locks as there is a next-key locks, and they realize their insertions are duplicate of each other.